# How can I access the "this" of an angular js controller, from inside a promise method?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have simple angular js controller making a XHR request as below

```
app.controller('MainController', ['$http', function($http) {

    this.php_response = {};

    var promise = $http.get('process.php');

    promise.then(
        function(success_data) {

            // I dont think "this" is talking to the controller this anymore?    
            this.php_response = success_data;

        }, function(error) {
            console.log('there was a problem');
        }
    );

}]);
```

When I wrote this controller using `$scope` instead of this the code worked, now the `this.php_response` property is not containing the data retrieved from the XHR request.
I suspect the `promise.then#success` callback is no longer referencing the controller `this`.
How can I get access the this, inside the promise method?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) that preserves lexical context:

```
promise.then(success_data => {  
    this.php_response = success_data;
}, error => {
    console.log('there was a problem');
});
```

Another simple way is to bind context with [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) method:

```
promise.then(function(success_data) {  
    this.php_response = success_data;
}.bind(this), function(error) {
    console.log('there was a problem');
});
```

And finally, old-school way: define reference variable pointing to outer `this` and use it inside callback:

```
var self = this;

promise.then(function(success_data) {  
    self.php_response = success_data;
}, function (error) {
    console.log('there was a problem');
});
```

Whatever you prefer more.

Comment: thanks, I found they both worked,  `var self = this;` instantly made sense, so I will go with that in the future!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`angular.bind`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.bind) for this case

```
promise.then(angular.bind(this, function (success_data) {  
    this.php_response = success_data;
}), function (error) {
    console.log('there was a problem');
});
```